# Devise is giving me a routing error when logging out. Rails 4

Tags: devise, logout, routes

For some reason I can't log out of Devise, it keeps giving me a no route error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that destroy_user_session_path is a delete method. Your logout link should look like this:

```
<%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

Also, ensure that you have this inside application.js:

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```